# How to execute linux command from static js file Node.js + Vue.js + Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm really new with Node.js
I have static minified file `app.xxxxx.js` `manifest.xxxxx.js` `vendor.xxxxx.js` and bunch of chunks files like `0.xxxxx.js`.
I tried to modify `app.xxx.js` at the bottom of file with `const { exec } = require("child_process");` to execute linux command. But error returned on Chrome Console `require is not defined`.

How I execute linux command on server side with all of that files? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Node.js APIs directly in the browser. While many of them can be polyfilled with `webpack` or other technologies, `child_process` is not among them. You will not be able to spawn processes from the browser using `child_process`.

Without knowing more about the problem you are trying to solve, it is difficult to offer more information than that. (For example: Are you trying to spawn a process on the client or on the server?) But I hope it helps get you going in the right direction to at least know that this is not a path that is going to work.

If you are trying to create a process on the server, then a common way to do that would be to create an API endpoint on the server that your client-side code would access to launch the process on the server. The `child_process` code (or equivalent in another runtime if you are not running Node.js on the server) would exist on the server in that case, not in the webpack-created code served to the client.

Comment: I'm trying to spawn a process on the server.

Comment: I've added a paragraph explaining that one usual way to do that would be to create an API endpoint on the server that your client accesses to launch the process on the server. Hope that helps.